# Webscraping error in curl in R for one particular website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

I am trying to scrape a website using rvest package.  And whatever I have tried I have still problems with starting an html_session.

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)

session <- html_session("https://www.gpw.pl/spolki")

session <- httr::GET("https://www.gpw.pl/spolki")
```

For both of those I receive:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
 Failure when receiving data from the peer
```

Why is that? Is this website trying to block me from scraping?

**EDIT:** I am not able to find anything on their website that would explicitly state that they do not allow scraping. Are there different ways that would allow me to check whether spiders are allowed on this website?

If anybody has any interesting ideas as to how should I deal with this problem then do not hesitate to share them bellow this question :)

Comment: I also get an error here: `GnuTLS recv error (-110): The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.` It may be because the site is refusing connection. Do their terms of use allow web scraping?

Comment: I thought that they allow that. I am not able to find anything on their website. Could it be tested automatically somehow? I mean can i check automatically whether they allow webscraping or not?

Comment: Well it looks like they are blocking webscraping. Hard to say whether it is a bug or a feature... As a workaround, using the Network console in Firefox's web developer tools, you might be able to catch details of the HTTP connection that Firefox establishes (including headers such as user agent, etc) and mimick that from R with `httr::set_config(...)`

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get information from this website using RSelenium :

```
library(RSelenium)
shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.gpw.pl/spolki")
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
```